# How to use highlighter in pyLucene?

Tags: python, pylucene

I have read some tutorials about highlighting search terms in Lucene, and came up with a piece of code like this:

```
(...)
query = parser.parse(query_string)

for scoreDoc in  searcher.search(query, 50).scoreDocs:
    doc = searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc)
    filename = doc.get("filename")
    print filename
    found_paraghaph = fetch_from_my_text_library(filename)

    stream = lucene.TokenSources.getTokenStream("contents", found_paraghaph, analyzer);
    scorer = lucene.Scorer(query, "contents", lucene.CachingTokenFilter(stream))
    highligter = lucene.Highligter(scorer)
    fragment = highligter.getBestFragment(analyzer, "contents", found_paraghaph)
    print '>>>' + fragment
```

But it all ends with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./search.py", line 76, in <module>
    scorer = lucene.Scorer(query, "contents", lucene.CachingTokenFilter(stream))
NotImplementedError: ('instantiating java class', <type 'Scorer'>)
```

So, I guess, that this part of Lucene insn't iplemented yet in pyLucene. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too got similar error. I think this class's wrapper is not yet implemented for Pylucene v3.6.

You might want to try the following:

```
analyzer = StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT)

# Constructs a query parser.
queryParser = QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, FIELD_CONTENTS, analyzer)

# Create a query
query = queryParser.parse(QUERY_STRING)

topDocs = searcher.search(query, 50)

# Get top hits
scoreDocs = topDocs.scoreDocs
print "%s total matching documents." % len(scoreDocs)

HighlightFormatter = SimpleHTMLFormatter();
highlighter = Highlighter(HighlightFormatter, QueryScorer (query))

for scoreDoc in scoreDocs:
    doc = searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc)
    text = doc.get(FIELD_CONTENTS)
    ts = analyzer.tokenStream(FIELD_CONTENTS, StringReader(text))
    print doc.get(FIELD_PATH)
    print highlighter.getBestFragments(ts, text, 3, "...")
    print ""
```

Please note that we create token stream for each item in the search result.

Comment: thanks! Seems that the most important part here is creating `QueryScorer` instead of `Scorer` - now, when I looked it up in Lucene's documentation, I found out that `Scorer` is an abstract class, so that's why this error come up. And name `NotImplementedError` is quite misleading here...

Comment: The code works great. One thing to mention, The `StringReader` is import from `java.io`, not from `lucene`.